# Как делается приложение, которое работает в фоне, но реагирует на определенные пользовательские события?

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, а как делаются приложения, которые работают в фоне(Например, свернутые), но в тоже время, реагирующие на действия пользователя?

Например, пользователь что-то делает вне окна приложения, нажимает какую-то комбинацию кнопок и фоновое приложение проделывает какую-то работу.

Что нужно использовать, для реализации такого эффекта ?

Это реализуемо только в WinForms или с консольным тоже ?

Если можно, то приведите банальный пример реализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение своего вопроса с примером:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/